# Background appears to be above button in SwiftUI. Am I doing it wrong

Tags: button, background, swiftui, sections

I am slowly building up an app using SwiftUI that uses Sections to group custom views. The custom controls have buttons. Everything worked as I expected until I added a background to the sections.

After trying to debug the code attached to the buttons I took a dump of the view hierarchy and there I could see that the buttons appeared to be covered by the background.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Section(header: Text("Two rows")) {
                Row()
                Row()
            }
        }
        .padding(.all, 12)
        //.background(Color.gray, cornerRadius: 5)
        .border(Color.black, width: 1, cornerRadius: 5)
    }
}

struct Row: View {
    @State var item = "0"

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(
                action: { self.item += "+" },
                label: { Image(systemName: "plus.circle") }
            )
            Text(item)
            Button(
                action: { self.item += "-" },
                label: { Image(systemName: "minus.circle") }
            )
        }

    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View { ContentView() }
}
#endif
```

The code as shown doesn't do very much, the buttons just append + or - to the 0. When the .background() line is uncommented though the buttons don't work.

It appears that sections are a tupple of views and the borders and backgrounds are applied to all of them rather than the group which is why I added the outermost vstack

Comment: Using `Image(systemName: "minus.circle").tapAction { self.item += "-" }` instead of `Button` seems to work well. Tapping the `Button` labels actually works too. You just need to be very precise.

Comment: That works quite well although not always, I think that you have to hit the dark part of the image for it to work. I'd still like to know why the background appears to be above the button though.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure why this is the case, but the hit-box on the button appears to essentially disappear when you add the background. I'm assuming this is a bug, but maybe someone else can explain why this is happening.

As for the solution to the problem, I got your code to work by setting the frame on the image inside the button.

```swift
HStack {
    Button(action: { self.item += "+" }) {
        Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
    }
    Text(item)
    Button(action: { self.item += "-" }) {
        Image(systemName: "minus.circle")
            .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of: [SwiftUI: Custom button does not recognize touch with clear background and buttonStyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61352171/swiftui-custom-button-does-not-recognize-touch-with-clear-background-and-button)

Adding `.contentShape(Rectangle())` should work for this case as well.