# SwiftUI: Custom button does not recognize touch with clear background and buttonStyle

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode11

I stumbled upon a weird behaviour for `Button`s in SwiftUI in combination with a custom `ButtonStyle`.

My target was to create a custom `ButtonStyle` with some kind of 'push-back animation'. I used the following setup for this:

```swift
struct CustomButton<Content: View>: View {
    private let content: () -> Content

    init(content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: { ... }) {
                content()
            }
            .buttonStyle(PushBackButtonStyle(pushBackScale: 0.9))
        }
    }
}

private struct PushBackButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let pushBackScale: CGFloat

    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration
            .label
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? pushBackScale : 1.0)
    }
}

// Preview
struct Playground_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CustomButton {
            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                HStack {
                    Text("Button Text").background(Color.orange)
                }

                Divider()

                HStack {
                    Text("Detail Text").background(Color.orange)
                }
            }
        }
        .background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

When I now try to touch on this button outside of the `Text` view, nothing will happen. No animation will be visible and the action block will not be called.

[image: showcase]

What I found out so far:

- when you remove the `.buttonStyle(...)` it does work as expected (no custom animation of course)
- or when you set a `.background(Color.red))` on the `VStack` in the `CustomButton` it does also work as expected in combination with the `.buttonStyle(...)`

The question now is if anybody have a better idea of how to properly work around this issue or how to fix it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just add hit testing content shape in your custom button style, like below

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

```
private struct PushBackButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let pushBackScale: CGFloat

    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration
            .label
            .contentShape(Rectangle())     // << fix !!
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? pushBackScale : 1.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: I wasted an hour of my life trying to fix this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a .frame and it should work.
To make it easily testable I have rewritten it like this:

```
struct CustomButton: View {

    var body: some View {
                    Button(action: {  }) {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            HStack {
                Text("Button Text").background(Color.orange)
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.orange)
            }

            Divider()

            HStack {
                Text("Detail Text").background(Color.orange)
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.orange)
            }
                        }
    }
        .buttonStyle(PushBackButtonStyle(pushBackScale: 0.9))
    }
}

private struct PushBackButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let pushBackScale: CGFloat

    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration
            .label
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? pushBackScale : 1.0)
    }
}
```

I hope I could help. :-)

@Edit With video.

[image]

Comment: I see what you are thinking of. That might work in this use-case but in more complex use-cases where also a `Spacer()` is present, it does not work anymore as the `Text` can't have the full width / height.

Comment: See my minimal edited answer with a Spacer(). It does work as intented. Text in SwiftUI takes as much place as we allow it to take with ".infinity". You could also define a value of course.

Comment: But my original use-case was with a `Stack` and `Spacer` **inside** of the `Button` as you can see in my `Playground_Previews`. There I think it will not work.

Comment: Added this scenario in my answer and made a video to show you that it works. Nevertheless is Asperis answer good too of course.